# Pointer to void in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, void, void-pointers

I'm reading some code in the [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org) implementation and I can't understand what a `void *` type variable means. What does a pointer to `void` mean in C++?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A pointer to void, `void*` can point to any object:

```
int a = 5;
void *p = &a;

double b = 3.14;
p = &b;
```

You can't dereference, increment or decrement that pointer, because you don't know what type you point to. The idea is that `void*` can be used for functions like `memcpy` that just copy memory blocks around, and don't care about the type that they copy.

Comment: waw - I didn't realize you couldn't increment a void* !  thanks!

Comment: Quite a few compilers will let you - they assume that all pointer types are 32bit. This is wrong but common on Windows where people assume a 32bit x86.

Comment: @mgb: Never ever seen such a compiler.

Comment: I saw one that treated it like char* for arithmatic, which makes sense when you think about it.

Comment: i don't think it makes sense. why should p++; increment it by one? could aswell increment by the pagesize or some other value. since sizeof(*p) is Big Fail, i'm lost at seeing how it could ever make sense :)

Comment: example compiler: gcc allows void pointer arithmetic and treats it like char*.  Such code is nonportable, but possible in GNU-land.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a generic pointer, used to pass data when you don't know the type. You have to cast it to the correct type in order to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a raw pointer to a spot in memory. It doesn't allow any pointer arithmetic like char * or int *.

Here's some examples of usage

http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/programming/node87.html

Answer (score 2):

It's a pointer to *anything* -- just a chunk of memory that you can play with -- might be an object, might be a char. You have to cast to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Building off my prior posting...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406010/passing-pointer-to-an-array-of-arrays-through-function#406274)

---

**ATTENTION:** All memory addresses here are fictional. I'm just making them up to illustrate a point.

---

Given:

```
int data[] = {10,11,12};
```

We now have:

```
0xffff0000-0xffff0003  with a value of (int)(10)
0xffff0004-0xffff0007  with a value of (int)(11)
0xffff0008-0xffff000b  with a value of (int)(12)
```

(I'm **not** going to get into big-endian vs little-endian byte ordering here.)

If we have:

```
int * p = data;
```

We now have another memory location somewhere else, say:

```
 0xaaaa0000-0xaaaa0003  with a value of (int*)0xffff0000
```

We can use *p[1]* [or *(p + 1)] to refer to *(int*)(0xffff0004) [=11] as sizeof(int)=4 and 0xffff0000+sizeof(int) = 0xffff0004.

If we have:

```
void * v = data;
```

We now have another memory location somewhere else, say:

```
 0xbbbb0000-0xbbbb0003  with a value of (void*)0xffff0000.
```

However, void doesn't have any associated sizeof() information.  We can't increment or decrement the pointer.    We can't dereference to access the data stored in 0xffff0000.  We can only utilize the value as a raw memory address.

If we want to use the data stored in (void*)0xffff0000, we first need to cast it to an appropriate type.

That said, (void *) is still quite useful as a means of passing addresses to arbitrary data structures around.  For instance, memset().  It doesn't matter whether I'm zero'ing out a *struct tm* or a *struct sockaddr*.  We just need a pointer to the struct and its size.

(This should go without saying, but...  Beware using memset to zero out a class instance and, in doing so, overwriting the virtual pointer table.)

Answer (score 1):

A void pointer cannot point to a class member in C++.

Comment: i think that is because member pointers are completely different structured. If you want, then you can say they live in another address space (and then the reason is the same as the reason you cannot point to a function using `void*`). For sizes, a data member pointer on GCC (following the Itanium ABI) will have the size of a `ptrdiff_t` - it equals the size of an `int*` on my PC - the address space is the offset from the start of the object to its last member offset. For pointers to member functions, the size is usually bigger, in addition, of course.